# Das Keyboard Refurbished Professional Model S: What does "Refurbished" mean?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, past-participles

Everything is in the question, so I copy/paste:

Das Keyboard Refurbished Professional Model S: what does "Refurbished" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Refurbished* means "returned and/or used item which the factory has spruced up to like-new condition, or so they would have you believe". It's different from second-hand in that generally, it comes with a manufacturer's warranty.

None of the dictionaries I checked have this meaning — they only give the more literal "renovated, restored" definitions.

Comment: Yes but what are they more expensive than the new Model? °_°

Comment: If they're selling refurbished keyboards for *more* than brand-new keyboards, I would suggest running away^H^H^H^H^H^H^H finding a different vendor.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant: *why* are they more expensive than the new Model? °_°

Comment: @Olivier Pons, the answer is: they shouldn't be. If a vendor is trying to sell a refurbished keyboard for more money than an equivalent brand-new one, then there is something really screwy going on, and I would suggest staying far away from said vendor. A refurbished item is, by definition, used, and thus should cost *less* than the equivalent item when it's brand-new.

Comment: @Martha: your answer seems to be a bit prejudicial about refurbished items. The literal "restored" definition is what is intended when a manufacturer sells a refurbished item.  Sometimes the product was found to be defective right after manufacture but was repaired for sale. In my experience in the IT world the refurbished products from some cheaper companies were actually more reliable than their factory-new products. Anyway, refurbished is meant to mean "restored". Whether the product is "used" (a word with strong connotations) cannot be inferred.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New, the OP is trying to make sense of a website that is not in his native language; I don't think it's helpful to him to digress into Politically Correct Land and start debating the relative merits of "pre-owned" vs. "refurbished" vs. "used". Not to mention, such a debate would be off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Martha: Actually I think a debate about the distinctions between the meanings of those words would be on-topic, but maybe unanswerable.  In any case, I was just pointing out that your answer seems to say that the literal meaning is wrong, while the true (modern) meaning implies deception from the vendor. Seems like a stretch to me.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: eh? All of "restored", "refurbished", "repaired", "used", "pre-owned", "second-hand", and "spruced up" share the meaning of "not new". As such, *by definition* they should cost less than the *same item* when new. (Naturally, this only applies if said item can still be obtained new. And it only applies to equivalent items, where the definition of "equivalent" can be quite restrictive depending on the product.)

Comment: @Martha: Those words are all related.  But "used" has a connotation that's different from "restored", or "repaired".  And "refurbished" means "restored" without needing the jab of "... or so they'd have you believe".

Comment: (typing this on a Das Keyboard Model S Ultimate Silent, not refurbished) just as a general possibility in some cases if the manufacturing process has changed to a less expensive process some people might want items that were manufactured using the old process for either rational or irrational reasons, and if the demand for those items is high enough, then it might make sense for refurbished products to cost more than new ones. Just sayin'

Comment: Refurbished is also often used for legal/marketing reasons. Apple don't have sales - but will sell "refurbished" items, especially of the old model when a new model comes out. The refurbished items have never been sold or used - but it's phrased this way to put off some people who would then go and buy the brand new model. On high end products the makers might only allow authorized dealers to sell the product, or fix the minimum price. By listing them as refurbished other shops can sell them or sell at reduced prices.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refurbish):

> **to refurbish**
>
> 1. To rebuild or replenish with all new material; to restore to original (or better) working order and appearance.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refurbish):

> **refurbish**
>
> to brighten or freshen up

Collins English Dictionary:

> **refurbish**
>
> to make neat, clean, or complete, as by renovating, re-equipping, or restoring

Answer (score 1):

Refurbished in this usage likely means the product was bought by someone and returned due to a defect, or recalled; the manufacturer "fixed" the problem and is re-selling the item.

The original problem may range from something generally inconsequential to very important, but typically the warranty @Martha refers to should cover the product for some time AND you should get quite a bit of cash knocked off the price.